# Unit testing a method that calls another method that returns null no matter what

Tags: c#, unit-testing, null, nunit, rhino-mocks

I have a method in my controller.

```
public JsonResult GetMemberSubgroupSpecifications(int rows, int page)
    {
        List<VersionSpecification> versionSpecifications = _sessionAccessor.Contract.VersionSpecifications
            .Where(x => x.SpecificationType.Id == (int)SpecificationTypes.MemberSubGroup).ToList();
        List<MemberSubGroup> subGroups = _sessionAccessor.MemberSubGroups;

        if (subGroups == null)
        {
            subGroups = _subGroups.GetMemberSubGroups();
        }
        else if (subGroups.Count == 0)
        {
            subGroups = _subGroups.GetMemberSubGroups();
        }

        var specificationValues = versionSpecifications.GroupBy(x => x.Value).ToDictionary(r => r.Key, z => z.First());

        List<MemberSubGroup> contractMemberSubGroups = subGroups.Where(x => specificationValues.ContainsKey(x.Id)).ToList();

        _sessionAccessor.MemberSubGroups = contractMemberSubGroups;

        var jsonData = contractMemberSubGroups.Select(x => new
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            MemberSubGroupName = x.SubGroupName,
            MemberGroupName = x.MemberGroup.GroupName,
            MemberGroupId = x.MemberGroup.Id,
            SubGroupCode = x.SubGroupCode,
            StartDate = specificationValues[x.Id].StartDate,
            EndDate = specificationValues[x.Id].EndDate
        }).ToList();

        var json = _jsonHelper.FormatContractDetailsJsonData(rows, page, jsonData);

        return json;
```

When trying to write a unit test for this method, I can't get

```
_jsonHelper.FormatContractDetailsJsonData(rows, page, jsonData);
```

to return anything but null.

Here's my unit test for the method.

```
    [Test]
    public void GetMemberSubGroupsSpecifications_ReturnsJson()
    {
        //Arrange
        var jsonHelper = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IJsonHelper>();
        jsonHelper.Stub(x => x.FormatContractDetailsJsonData(Arg<int>.Is.Anything, Arg<int>.Is.Anything, Arg<List<object>>.Is.Anything)).Return(new JsonResult() { });

        var specificationType = MockRepository.GenerateMock<SpecificationType>();
        specificationType.Id = 2;

        var versionSpecification = MockRepository.GenerateMock<VersionSpecification>();
        versionSpecification.SpecificationType = specificationType;
        versionSpecification.Value = 2;

        var sessionAccessor = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISessionAccessor>();

        var memberGroup = MockRepository.GenerateMock<MemberGroup>();
        memberGroup.GroupName = "groupName";
        memberGroup.Id = 2;
        var memberGroups = new List<MemberGroup>()
        {
            memberGroup
        };

        var contractVersion = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ContractVersion>();
        contractVersion.VersionSpecifications = new List<VersionSpecification>()
        {
            versionSpecification
        };

        var memberSubGroup = MockRepository.GenerateMock<MemberSubGroup>();
        memberSubGroup.Id = 2;
        memberSubGroup.MemberGroup = memberGroup;
        memberSubGroup.SubGroupCode = "subGroupCode";

        var listMemberSubGroups = new List<MemberSubGroup>()
        {
            memberSubGroup
        };

        sessionAccessor.Stub(x => x.MemberGroups).Return(memberGroups);
        sessionAccessor.Stub(x => x.Contract).Return(contractVersion);
        sessionAccessor.Stub(x => x.MemberSubGroups).Return(listMemberSubGroups);

        var searchController = ObjectFactory.GetSearchController(sessionAccessor, null, null, jsonHelper);

        //Act
        var actual = searchController.GetMemberSubgroupSpecifications(1, 1);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
        Assert.IsInstanceOf(typeof(JsonResult), actual);
    }
```

I've been struggling with this for a few days now and I can't find any thing that would help me in any of my searches.
Also, I'm still fairly new to using rhino mocks and unit testing in general.

Here is the FormatContractDetailsToJson method:

```
    public JsonResult FormatContractDetailsJsonData<T>(int rows, int page, List<T> data)
    {
        var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(data.Count / (float)rows);

        JsonResult json = new JsonResult();

        json.Data = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page,
            records = data.Count,
            rows = data
        };

        json.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;

        return json;
    }
```

I believe the list data parameter is the reason why this is happening, but I'm not sure.

Comment: That one controller method is doing way too many things.  You should decompose it so you can test them individually.  This one method is a) getting the proper groups, b) getting the proper specifications, c) transforming groups + specs into a type (that you might want to de-anonymize), d) transforming a list of your new type into JSON.

Comment: I agree thoroughly. We were in a bit of a time crunch last sprint and this is the combined efforts of 3 different devs trying to make sure a story passes. I'd like to factor it out, but I would probably need a story to be able to invest the amount of time it would take to really clean up that controller.

Comment: I'm also not 100% sure what you're looking to accomplish with your test - you're only verifying that you can successfully mock `IJsonHelper.FormatContractDetailsJsonData()`.  You're not interested in the results of the call, you're interested in verifying that the call gets made, which is what a mock object provides you (if you verify your assertions).

Comment: The original purpose of the test was to make sure that GetMemberSubGroupSpecifications returned a value that was not null and of type JsonResult. It's a poor test. What you see now is the result of frustration coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got types mismatch in your setup code:

```
jsonHelper.Stub(x => x.FormatContractDetailsJsonData(
       Arg<int>.Is.Anything,
       Arg<int>.Is.Anything,
       Arg<List<object>>.Is.Anything))
   .Return(new JsonResult() { });
```

In your tested code 3rd parameter won't be a list of objects - it will be list of compiler generated anonymous type instances against which you are not making any setups.

In other words, your tests make setup to:

```
FormatContractDetailsJsonData<object>
```

While your implementation calls more or less:

```
FormatContractDetailsJsonData<<>f_AnonymousType...>
```

There is a hack however. **If** your tests live in the same assembly as your tested code you can generate dummy of such type by simply declaring yet another anonymous type with **properties with the same names, types and order**:

```
var dummyList = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 1)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Id = 1,
        MemberSubGroupName = "",
        MemberGroupName = "",
        MemberGroupId = 1,
        SubGroupCode = "",
        StartDate = DateTime.Now,
        EndDate = DateTime.Now,
    })
    .ToList();
```

And set up your mock like this:

```
jsonHelper.Stub(x => x.FormatContractDetailsJsonData(1, 1, dummyList))
    .IgnoreArguments()
    .Return(new JsonResult() { });
```

Unfortunately, if this is not the case (anonymous types originating from the same assembly), you'll most likely have to create separate type for `jsonData` to make your matching work.